# Get Instance of RootView in the AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios

How do I get an instance of RootViewController in order to use code like:

```
rootViewController.progressView.progress = 0.7
```

in the `applicationDidFinishLauching` method in the App Delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `IBOutlet` of a float variable in your `rootViewController`.Then you can init that variable in applicationDidFinishLaunching by the same code that you showed like this

```
rootViewController.progress = 0.7;
```

and in `viewDidLoad` method of `rootViewController` you can then show the progress of your progress View to 70 % or what ever you want.

Apparently you cannot do

```
rootViewController.progressView.progress = 0.7;
```

coz your progressView object is in archived state or frozen state or something like that. 
so I think you can use this as a solution to your problem.

hope this helps

Comment: Hm...thats bad. The AppDelegate should change the progress several times. The rootViewController would have to poll if there are changes. Well, it's not so important. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#import "CBAppDelegate.h"
#import "OPStringLocalization.h"

@implementation CBAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController* rootController = [self.window rootViewController];
    [rootController localizeStrings];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

you usually have an instance available as an instance variable of the window object:

```
self.window.rootViewController
```

Comment: Can you give me please a piece of code how i could access the progressView, that is in the RootViewController? I tried ` RootViewController *rootViewController =  self.window.rootViewController;
 rootViewController.progressView.progress = 0.7;`